# Получение элемента с неразрывным пробелом &nbsp через XPath

Tags: selenium, xpath

Есть элемент страницы, содержащий неразрывный пробел:

```
<a>Foo&nbsp;Bar</a>
```

Пробую его получить через XPath: `//a[text()='Foo Bar']`, но selenium не находит этот элемент. Как получить этот элемент через XPath?

Comment: Как вариант реплейснуть &nbsp; -> " " в самом доке и потом уже искать. Эффективность, конечно, не очень.

Comment: @maxwell не получится, это веб страница, которая обновляется, есть страшное и ужасное решение через`//a[text()[contains(.,'Foo')] and text()[contains(.,'Bar')]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать его юникод код - `//a[text()='Foo\u00a0Bar']`.

Comment: Да, это правильный ответ, спасибо. И как ни странно, через браузер это работает, а через python и Selenium пришлось кое-что доделывать.